# Selenium Webdriver Python fails with url that has params

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Let's take [this sample code](https://github.com/namgivu/selenium-start/commit/ccc17bd27a29a05cc113d344b6b9e00d180a704e) to see that

1. It can run with `google.com/search?q=abb`
2. Cannot run with `tiki.vndien-gia-dung/c1882?src=mega-menu`.

I really don't get why it fails ie. how to work around with it?

My [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=selenium%20webdriver%20python%20fails%20at%20url%20with%20param&oq=selenium%20webdriver%20python%20fails%20at%20url%20with%20param&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.212j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [search on our site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=selenium%20webdriver%20python%20fails%20at%20url%20with%20param) result [little helpful](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/7343).

```
#this is working
driver.get('https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=abb')
print(driver.title)

#TODO this not working, why?
driver.get('https://www.tiki.vn/dien-gia-dung/c1882?src=mega-menu')
print(driver.title)
```

The error thrown as below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/namgivu/NN/code/_NN_/selenium-start/run180306.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver.get('https://www.tiki.vn/dien-gia-dung/c1882?src=mega-menu')   File "/Users/namgivu/NN/code/_NN_/selenium-start/venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 250, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})   File "/Users/namgivu/NN/code/_NN_/selenium-start/venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 238, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/Users/namgivu/NN/code/_NN_/selenium-start/venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash from tab crashed   (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux
4.9.60-linuxkit-aufs x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 2.38 seconds Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info: host: '63dbc8024ccd', ip: '172.17.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.60-linuxkit-aufs', java.version: '1.8.0_131' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57), userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.0zu965}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=59.0.3071.115, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}] Session ID: 46c06e57177e521c3221b0f75fe71630 Screenshot: available via screen Stacktrace:
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:-2)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable (ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed (ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute (RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get (RemoteWebDriver.java:364)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke (EventFiringWebDriver.java:104)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.get (None:-1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.get (EventFiringWebDriver.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ChangeUrl.call (ChangeUrl.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ChangeUrl.call (ChangeUrl.java:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run (DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Why do you think it fails? What does "not working" mean? What is it doing that is different than what you expect? Is it throwing an error? Is it returning the wrong data?

Comment: It throws error as updated question - something like "session deleted because of page crash from tab crashed"